# PHP - PHPExcel Range to Array ignores empty column

Tags: php, laravel, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

I have below the Excel sheet, where I want to get the range `A1:D4` into a PHP array.

[image]

For this, I am using `PHPExcel` as below. I have a simple `Excel` class:

`Excel.php`

```php
public function __construct($file)
{
     if ($file instanceof \SplFileInfo) {
         $filename = $file->getRealPath();
     } else {
         $filename = $file;
     }

     $this->objPHPExcel = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load($filename);
     $this->objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
}
```

And then I have a simple function to get the range, using the [rangeToArray()](http://hitautodestruct.github.io/PHPExcelAPIDocs/classes/PHPExcel_Worksheet.html#method_rangeToArray) function:

```php
public function getRange($range)
{
    $spreadsheet = $this->objPHPExcel;
    return $spreadsheet->rangeToArray($range,'  ', true, true, true);

}

$excel = new ExcelManipulator(storage_path() . '/app/temp_files/myfile.xlsx');
$array = $excel->getRange($range);

return response()->json(['result' => $array], 200);
```

Now the problem is that the above function "switches" the columns. See below output:

```php
[
  '1': [
     "A": "  ", 
     "B": "  ",
     "C": "  ",
     "D": "  "
  ],
  '2': [
     "A": "Company", 
     "B": "Acme Inc",
     "C": "  ",
     "D": "  "
  ],
  '3': [
     "A": "Address", 
     "B": "New York",
     "C": "  ",
     "D": "  "
  ],
  '4': [
     "A": "  ", 
     "B": "  ",
     "C": "  ",
     "D": "  "
  ]
]
```

As you can see in the array for row `2` and `3`, the **company** and **address** text starts already in `Column A`, while they should start in `Column B`

Comment: Hi @oliverbj, just checking if you're using the [phpoffice/phpspreadsheet](https://packagist.org/packages/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet) package and not the deprecated [phpoffice/phpexcel](https://packagist.org/packages/phpoffice/phpexcel) right?

Comment: @DelenaMalan Yes, I am using the phpspreadsheet package:  `\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet`

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. What version are you using? Also, are you assigning `$this->objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)` to anything? Because right now it looks like you're calling `rangeToArray` on the spreadsheet instead of on the worksheet.

Comment: what is your defined `$range`?

Comment: Problem is probably coming from the $range variable. Can you please post a little more context ?

Comment: Please send the result of `var_dump($spreadsheet->rangeToArray('A1:D4','  ', true, true, true))`, `var_dump((array)$spreadsheet->rangeToArray('A1:D4','  ', true, true, true))` and `var_dump($spreadsheet->rangeToArray('A1:D4','  ', true, true, false))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try it

```
function getRange($range, $inputFileName)
{
    $spreadsheet = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load($inputFilename);
    return $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->rangeToArray($range," ", true, true, true);

}
$inputFilename = storage_path() . '/app/temp_files/myfile.xlsx';
$array = getRange($range, $inputFilename);
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked fine for me using php 7.2.26 and phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 1.10.1. I created an xlsx file with the same cell values as yours.

```
$excel = new Excel('file.xlsx');
$range = 'A1:D4';
$array = $excel->getRange($range);

var_dump($array);

class Excel
{
  private $objPHPExcel;

  public function __construct($file)
  {
     if ($file instanceof \SplFileInfo) {
         $filename = $file->getRealPath();
     } else {
         $filename = $file;
     }

     $this->objPHPExcel = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load($filename);
     $this->objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
  }

  public function getRange($range)
  {
    $spreadsheet = $this->objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
    return $spreadsheet->rangeToArray($range,'  ', true, true, true);
  }
}
```

And this is the output:

```
array(4) {
  [1] =>
  array(4) {
    'A' =>
    string(2) "  "
    'B' =>
    string(2) "  "
    'C' =>
    string(2) "  "
    'D' =>
    string(2) "  "
  }
  [2] =>
  array(4) {
    'A' =>
    string(2) "  "
    'B' =>
    string(7) "Company"
    'C' =>
    string(8) "Acme Inc"
    'D' =>
    string(2) "  "
  }
  [3] =>
  array(4) {
    'A' =>
    string(2) "  "
    'B' =>
    string(7) "Address"
    'C' =>
    string(8) "New York"
    'D' =>
    string(2) "  "
  }
  [4] =>
  array(4) {
    'A' =>
    string(2) "  "
    'B' =>
    string(2) "  "
    'C' =>
    string(2) "  "
    'D' =>
    string(2) "  "
  }
}
```